# Redux Reducer is being called twice, leading to error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am using Redux with middleware and multiple reducers. My `store.js` looks like this:

```js
const reducer = combineReducers({
  userReducer,
  watchListReducer,
  itemsReducer,
});

export const CombinedStore = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

And I use it like so in `App.tsx`

```js
<Provider store={CombinedStore}>
// my app
</Provider>
```

I have the following function which fetches relevant UserData:

```
const loadUserDataRedux = async () => {
    setLoading(true);

    let userBuilder = new OnlineUserBuilder();

    if (authData) {
      await userBuilder.initialize();
      await userBuilder.setProfile();
      await userBuilder.setInventory();
      await userBuilder.setAdditionalInfo();
      await userBuilder.setWatchLists();
      await userBuilder.setOfflineData();
      let user = userBuilder.build();

      setUserData(user); 
      console.log("calling redux");
      dispatch(setUser(user));
    }
    setLoading(false);
  };
```

This method is being called intentionally in useEffect of my `App.tsx`.

**Actions.js**

```js
export const setUser = (user: UserData) => (dispatch: any) => {
  dispatch({
    type: SET_USER,
    payload: user,
  });
};
```

**Reducer.js**

```js
case SET_USER:
      console.log("-->", action.payload.id);
      return { ...state, user: action.payload };
```

so the output looks like this:

```
... other output ...
calling redux
--> 123434567
... other output ...
--> undefined
```

Expected:

```
... other output ...
calling redux"
--> 123434567
... other output ...
```

At some places, I use the data of `user` by using `useSelector`. But somehow, `console.log()` inside `Reducer.js` is called twice. The first time, everything is fine and the data is being displayed correctly, but with a delay of ca. 1 sec, `Reducer.js` is being called again, but obviously without any `payload`, which results in empty redux store.

I have read, that this is the expected behaviour for redux and I tried using `React.StrictMode´ but not working.

This cant be the desired behaviour for Redux, right??

Comment: Do you have any other places where dispatch(setUser()) is being called? Or other places where the SET_USER action type is being dispatched?

Comment: No, I also updated the output-code of my question, as you can now see, the first output is led by `calling redux` output, while the second `--> undefined` output does not have `calling redux`, so the second time, it is not called by the `dispatch()` method, but somehow magically...

Comment: Check to make sure the action type SET_USER doesn't have the same value as some other action type. For example SET_USER = 'setUser', SOME_OTHER_TYPE = 'setUser'

Comment: Do a string search for `SET_USER` and make sure it's not appearing anywhere else, and also a search for `setUser`. It may be being kicked off from somewhere else unintentionally. Also, the interface for `setUser` is kinda strange/complex, instead of currying the function, just make it simply `(user: UserData) => { type: SET_USER, payload: user }`. I doubt that's causing the issue, but it's simpler.

Comment: it was actually @AsenMitrev's comment, thanks, I feel so stupid :)))